# How to recognize a ball from an image

Tags: graphics, image-processing, 3d, computer-vision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recognize a ball in an image and then model it in 3D(HawkEye System)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729005/how-to-recognize-a-ball-in-an-image-and-then-model-it-in-3dhawkeye-system)

hello,
now in my attempt to develop HawkEye System (as explained in my previously asked ques:
   [How to recognize a ball in an image and then model it in 3D(HawkEye System)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729005/how-to-recognize-a-ball-in-an-image-and-then-model-it-in-3dhawkeye-system) )

i am shooting the video of the batsman from two different angles simultaneously, one from leg side and the other from the front and using 'Video Decompiler' Software i am able to break the two videos into 30 frames/sec.
So now i have the position of the ball at different instants of time from two different angles, now what i intend to do is plotting the position of the ball got from every frame into 3D using opengl so that by joining all those plotted points i can get the trajectory of the ball. i'll be repeating this whole process for both the videos and finally merge both the trajectories to get the 'somewhat' original trajectory of the ball

Now the real problem is that i need a way to recognize the ball from the different frames and then describe that position as (x,y) coordinate w.r.t. some reference point(say the wickets) and i need to do this in an automated way bcs there's no way i'm going to some 120 frames and manually find the coordinates.
i believe that opencv would the best image recognition library for this task

in short i need a program using opencv where i give all the frames as input and then i get the coordinates for all those frames in one go

please help me out in accomplishing this